# Trigger not firing on operation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Created a trigger on a table which compiled and message "Trigger Created" was displayed.

But on operation on the particular table, the trigger does not fire.

What could be the issue or is there a catch here?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the trigger code and the SQL that you expect to fire the trigger. And tell us which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Im using Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Check if the trigger is valid and enabled:

```
SELECT * FROM User_Objects t WHERE t.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TRIGGER';
SELECT t.* FROM User_Triggers  t;
```

Comment: I ran the commands and it returns no rows selected. So its not valid.  how do i make it valid now?

Comment: The second query returns all the triggers and my trigger i missing.. How do i go about it now?

Comment: If it's invalid you should edit the trigger and recompile it again, maybe it has syntax error or other objects which this trigger is related to is invalid.

Comment: The 2nd query has status column is it enable?

Comment: the 2nd query returns " no rows returned" when i add the "where name = trigger_name" clause. so trigger is not registered (if thats what i can call it)

Comment: If your trigger is not in data dictionary then it doesn't exist. You should compile it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **oracle**, you can try enabling the trigger

```
    ALTER TABLE tblName ENABLE TRIGGER trgName --WRONG
```

Correcting the syntax(thanks for the comment) :

```
    ALTER TRIGGER trg_name ENABLE;
```

To check if your trigger exists, valid/invalid, etc.:

```
    SELECT * from dba_triggers WHERE LOWER(trigger_name) LIKE '%salupdate%';
    SELECT * FROM dba_objects WHERE LOWER(object_name) LIKE '%salupdate%';
```

The user is using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE in trigger which is not seen in output, following solves the issue:

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
```

Comment: "ALTER TABLE fees ENABLE TRIGGER msg;" gives error msg "ORA 00905 missing keyword" –

Comment: im using oracle

Comment: SQL> alter table fees enable trigger msg;
alter table fees enable trigger msg
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Enabled the trigger by ALTER TRIGGER msg ENABLE;    Trigger was altered successfully.     Also altered table triggers using   ALTER TABLE enable all triggers:      table was altered successfully.   But trigger still not firing on update!

Comment: Can you share the pseduocode of your trigger script?

Comment: Since its on update, it should be something like, CREATE TRIGGER trg_name (BEFORE|AFTER) **UPDATE** ON tbl_name ... Did you used the operation UPDATE in your trigger syntax? Attaching 2 links for reference which might give some idea... https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_update.php and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm

Comment: yes i did add the UPDATE in the code. i think my trigger is not valid as when i run 'select t.* from user_triggers t ' i do not see my trigger in there but only system generated triggers.  how do i make my trigger valid or should i say how do i register my trigger?

Comment: I would say, please add the pseudocode of your trigger in the post. It would help others debug the issue.You can give the skeleton. No need to give the intricate details. Just the full hanger as is.

Comment: Cannot add a comment on other reply, so adding here. Please try dba_objects, dba_triggers, all_objects, all_triggers. Since you are not able to see your trigger in user_triggers..

Comment: CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER salupdate 
BEFORE UPDATE ON fees
for each row

DECLARE
    sal_diff number;

BEGIN
    sal_diff := :NEW.salary - :OLD.salary;
    dbms_output.put_line('Old salary is');
    dbms_output.put_line(:OLD.salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('New salary is');
    dbms_output.put_line(:NEW.salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('Difference in salary is');
    dbms_output.put_line(sal_diff);
END;
/

Comment: tried all the above options ... no rows selected... it does not exist anywhere though it compiles fine and rerturns "trigger created" message.  Apologies bout the code format.. not getting the edit right.

Comment: also operations on the trigger like ENABLE n DISABLE work just fine. But there is no trace of the trigger in the database. It certainly exists but i cant find the location.

Comment: See, since the operations are working fine, it implies your triggers exist and are valid. Your code also looks fine. In case you are actually using DBMS_OUTPUT in your trigger, then I have some more suggestions. I'm assuming you are using an IDE such as sqldeveloper. Please prorate these to your choice of IDE. 1. Make sure DBMS_OUTPUT is working your sessions. When connected, try a simple DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. Are you seeing the output? 2. In the same session try update, are you seeing the update? 3. In some IDEs you need to link DBMS_OUTPUT window to your current session.

Comment: 4. Try using SET SERVEROUTPUT ON https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/oracle-sqlplus-the/0596007469/re85.html 5. Replace DBMS_OUTPUT with some DML operations, do follow with a commit. This would make sure that yes the trigger is working. 6. For trigger not seen in tables, well I think you would have taken care, but still, use UPPER/LOWER: SELECT * from dba_triggers WHERE LOWER(trigger_name) LIKE '%salupdate%';

Comment: Hey thank you so much .. it worked!!!! 'SET SERVEROUTPUT ON' did the trick !!! but wht could be the issue with trigger not been traced in the database? Bcoz i still dont see it even after all the considerations are taken care of.

Comment: Share the exact query you are using to check the trigger in tables, shall see if can provide some input.

Comment: select * from all_triggers where trigger_name = 'salupdate';   also i do the same with dba_triggers, user_triggers.           Also i search in objects as "select * from all_objects where object_name = 'salupdate';"  and the same in dba_objects, user_objects.

Comment: Already said in one of the comments to use LOWER/UPPER function. The object names are default stored in UPPERCASE in the tables. Either use select * from all_triggers where LOWER(trigger_name) = 'salupdate'; OR user select * from all_triggers where UPPER(trigger_name) = 'SALUPDATE'; Similarly for all_objects/dba_objects/dba_triggers/user_triggers/user_objects.

Comment: Hey thanks a ton @Rogue Coder... yes that was the missing link!!  Appreciate your help !!